# Python Processes Dict Sending Over Socket

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I have processes set up like

```
manager = Manager();

nodes = manager.dict();

p1 = Process(target = advertise, args=(nodes,));
p1.start();
p2 = Process(target = receive, args=(nodes,));
p2.start();

def advertise(nodes):
    while(1):
        nts = json.dumps(nodes.copy());
        for k, v in nodes.items():
            # Creates a UDP socket
            mySocket = createSocket(getMyIP(), PORT);
            mySocket.connect((getMyIP(), v[1]));
            mySocket.send(("AD||" + nts).encode("ASCII"));
            mySocket.close();
        time.sleep(5);

def receive(nodes):
    while(1):
        mySocket = createSocket(getMyIP(), PORT);
        mySocket.bind((getMyIP(), PORT));
        try:
            data = mySocket.recv(4096).decode("ASCII").split("||");
            if(data[0] == "AD"):
                temp = json.loads(data[1]);
                #print("Received: " + str(temp));
            for k, v in temp.items():
                nodes[k] = [float(v[0]), int(v[1])];
        except:
            mySocket.close();
```

One of which receives a dict and updates values, one of which sends out a dict.
I can't json.dumps(nodes) because it says DictProxy is not jsondumpable, so I did nts = json.dumps(nodes.copy());

This works for the first time (the socket sends the dictionary correctly) but the second time the program just says

```
File "Dvr.py", line 40, in advertise
    nts = json.dumps(nodes.copy());
File "<string>", line 2, in copy
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 758, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

**1) Why does this only work for the first time the while loop loops?**

**2) How do I make it work everytime?**

Comment: I'm not sure because I don't know what library you are using for socket connection, but it might be that (in the second iteration) you are connecting a socket to an already opened connection to that IP and PORT (with library `socket` this is not allowed)

Answer (score 0):

**fixed**
I just used threading instead of processes so it's easier to have a global simple dictionary instead of having to share a dictionary across multiple processes' memory spaces